# I have a problem about length. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

Should the length be inherited from angular right? and why if (fileList.length> 0) MyPostsComponent.html: 7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read the 'length' of undefined property.

```
onFileSelection(event){
  const fileList: FileList = event.target.filse;

  if (fileList.length > 0){
    const file: File = fileList[0];
    this.myFire.uploadFile(file).then(data => {
      //TO DO
      this.notifier.display('success','Picture Uploaded!');
      console.log(data['fileUrl']);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.notifier.display('error', err.message);
    });
  }
}
```

on my html code

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelection($event)" placeholder="Upload a file" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg">
```

Comment: If the below answers doesn't work, then check what `fileList` contains.

Comment: I just checked. The answer by @rorschach is correct. It should be `const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;` But still you need to check for `null | undefined` before checking length of any object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const fileList: FileList = event.target.filse;`

You seem to have a typo there which will result in `fileList` being `undefined` as an event's target *definitely* does not contain a property named `filse`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change in you code something like...

```
const fileList: FileList = event.target.files || [];
```

i hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

That means fileList is null , add a null check as follows,

```
if (fileList && fileList.length > 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because your fileList is undefined, first you should check fileList is not undefined

```
onFileSelection(event){
      const fileList: FileList = event.target.filse;

      if (fileList && `enter code here`fileList.length > 0){
        const file: File = fileList[0];
        this.myFire.uploadFile(file).then(data => {
          //TO DO
          this.notifier.display('success','Picture Uploaded!');
          console.log(data['fileUrl']);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.notifier.display('error', err.message);
        });
      }
    }
```